# I met/have met many people

Tags: tense

1. *I **have met** many people **in the past few days***.
2. *I **met** many people **in the past few days***.

What is the difference between 1) and 2)? What is the time duration that *in the past few days* implies in each case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we are talking about a period that stretches from some point in the past to the present, we generally use the PRESENT PERFECT tense - typically after the use of words such as **past / since / recently**.

So prefer 1.

However, it is noticeable that many native English speakers are now using the SIMPLE PAST tense in this context, a growing trend among BBC correspondents, some of whom also are also using the SIMPLE PAST where the PAST PERFECT is the better choice.

**A few** is a small number. How many are indicated would depend on the context.  A few days is more than two and less than many. It's not possible to give an exact number.

Comment: I don't know where you got ***it is noticeable** [that Simple Past is displacing Past Perfect]* from, but I can't see any evidence of that when comparing [***I met many, I have met many***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&smoothing=3&corpus=26&year_end=2019&content=I+met+many%2CI+have+met+many&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20met%20many%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20have%20met%20many%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CI%20met%20many%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20have%20met%20many%3B%2Cc0) in Google Books. It seems to me both versions have consistently been about equally common for at least the past two centuries.

Comment: (But unquestionably, as a general principle, the Perfect form is to be preferred after ***recently, in the past few days***, etc.)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica  After a couple of decades as a BBC news producer (now retired) I wince every time I hear correspondents using the past tense when either the present perfect or past perfect is required....and it happens daily.